# Variables aren't being set in workflow in GitLab CICD

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm using GitLab's CI/CD, trying to set variables in the rule within the *workflow* section.
When checking the value of the variable later on, within a job it seems like the value wasn't set, though the condition is met.

I'm using GitLab community addition version 13.7.4

Following is my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - prep

variables:
  VAR1: "no value"

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"
      variables:
        VAR1: "Value"

job:
  stage: prep
  script:
    - echo "CI_COMMIT_BRANCH=$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH"
    - echo "VAR1=$VAR1"
```

And this is what the results look like:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong – `variables` in `workflow:rules:` have been introduced only in GitLab 13.11 ([ref](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflowrulesvariables)).